# I am 5 Controllers deep into a Storyboard, how do I programmatically pop back to the Official Initial Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard

I am 5 Controllers deep into a Storyboard, how do I programmatically and easily pop back to the Official Initial Controller?

Is there some one liner for this? What is the most elegant and simple solution?

Comment: Unwind segues is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - On your root VC, create an unwind method: something like:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToRoot:(UIStoryboardSegue*);
```

Then wire it up to "exit" in your storyboard. This is an unwind segue.

or 2 - In your fifth VC, pop back manually:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Comment: Hi Brian! Long time....last time we spoke I was an Android only dev. Now...I happen to not be using a navigationcontroller. for all 5 of my controllers. so this only pops me back 2 out of 5 controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is a one-liner:

`[self.navigationController popToViewController:(UIViewController *)];`

Of course you would replace `(UIViewController *)` with the view controller at the beginning of the nav stack.

Comment: also is there a callback in the initial controller that gets called after this?

Comment: That would only work if there is navigation controller and all the segues performed are of type "show".

Comment: @Rog you are 100% correct. I shouldn't have assumed he was using a nav controller.

Comment: I am not using a nav controller.

Comment: @hunterp re: your callback question, simply implement a method with signature `-(IBAction)unwindMethodName:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue in your initial view controller, then in your storyboard control drag from the view controller icon (yellow) to the exit icon and choose the unwind method you just created. Here's a screenshot of how to connect http://d1u2s20mo6at4b.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/unwind_segue_add_to_viewcontroller1.png

Comment: Ah, then yes I would use an unwind segue as @Rog suggested. :)